# SAM application template.yaml not creating dev environment apis

Tags: node.js, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam

I have an application with multiple environments (dev, stage, prod). I'm using AWS Codepipeline for ci/cd process.

Each environment have diff buildspec.yml and template.yaml files.

I got an issue with API Gateway stages. If dev environment code deployed apis must be deploed as https://xxxxx/dev/health

If stage environment code deployed APIs must be deployed as https://xxxxx/stage/health

If prod environment code deployed APIs must be deployed as https://xxxxx/prod/health

But when I build and deploy dev environment code. generating "stage" and "prod" apis. Not creating dev url.

Following is my dev-template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: ""


Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 59
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS'"
      AllowHeaders: "'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization, X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'" 
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
    Auth:
      AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: False

Resources:
  DEVDMSFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        Health:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /health
            Method: get
        
Outputs:
  Health:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for dev for Health function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/dev/health"
```

And stage-template.yaml

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: ""


Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 59
  Api:
    Cors:
      AllowMethods: "'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS'"
      AllowHeaders: "'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization, X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'" 
      AllowOrigin: "'*'"
    Auth:
      AddDefaultAuthorizerToCorsPreflight: False

Resources:
  DEVDMSFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: src/
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs14.x
      Architectures:
        - x86_64
      Events:
        Health:
          Type: Api 
          Properties:
            Path: /health
            Method: get
        
Outputs:
  Health:
    Description: "API Gateway endpoint URL for dev for Health function"
    Value: !Sub "https://${ServerlessRestApi}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com/Stage/health"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to locate the definition of APIGateway in your template file defined with the Type of `AWS::Serverless::Api`

You will need to define `Stage` property with the value of 'dev', 'stage' and 'prod' accordingly

Refer: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html#sam-api-stagename

> The name of the stage, which API Gateway uses as the first path segment in the invoke Uniform Resource Identifier (URI).